# Telling webpack a 3rd party module uses ES Modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, es6-modules

Before trying to explain it, I'll just jump straight into it:

- Create a next.js scaffold. `npx create-next-app`
- (optional) I've added typescript here. Rename any of the .js to .ts, then run `yarn dev`
- Install the 3rd-party library, in my case, openlayers. `yarn add ol`
- Adapt one of the openlayers examples into the app. For instance, this is my `pages/index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react'
import Map from 'ol/Map'
import View from 'ol/View'
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile'
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj'
import { OSM, TileDebug } from 'ol/source'

export default function() {
  const ref = React.useRef<any>()
  React.useEffect(() => {
    var osmSource = new OSM()
    new Map({
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: osmSource,
        }),
        new TileLayer({
          source: new TileDebug({
            projection: 'EPSG:3857',
            tileGrid: osmSource.getTileGrid(),
          }),
        }),
      ],
      target: ref.current,
      view: new View({
        center: fromLonLat([-0.1275, 51.507222]),
        zoom: 10,
      }),
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <div ref={ref} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Now we navigate to `http://localhost:3000` and get the following error:

```
/home/willian/Documentos/consumer/node_modules/ol/Map.js:4
import PluggableMap from './PluggableMap.js';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

So ok, this seems like openlayers exports esmodules but webpack is trying to consume them as commonjs (from the `cjs/loader` path). Is there any way I could tell webpack to parse the module as es-modules instead?

(adendum) On next.js you can modify the webpack config through the `next.config.js` file [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs#customizing-webpack-config). But what exactly should I change on the webpack config? Console.logging into the rules section currently outputs:

```
[ { test: /\.(tsx|ts|js|mjs|jsx)$/,
    include:
     [ '/home/willian/Documentos/consumer',
       /next-server[\\\/]dist[\\\/]lib/,
       /next[\\\/]dist[\\\/]client/,
       /next[\\\/]dist[\\\/]pages/,
       /[\\\/](strip-ansi|ansi-regex)[\\\/]/ ],
    exclude: [Function: exclude],
    use: { loader: 'next-babel-loader', options: [Object] } } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> own-answer after some months

You SHOULD not need to tell webback a module is es-modules.

A module tells consumers it uses es-modules by declaring an extra `module` key on package.json. It serves a similar purpuse as the `main` key, BUT `main` is usually understood as a commonjs build entry point.

There are probably other "magical" entry point flags on package.json that webpack has conventioned to understand, for instance, an angular build generates keys like "fesm2015" et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

have a try to add `/[\\\/]node_modules[\\\/]ol/` into include property?

---

```
include:
 [ '/home/willian/Documentos/consumer',
   /next-server[\\\/]dist[\\\/]lib/,
   /next[\\\/]dist[\\\/]client/,
   /next[\\\/]dist[\\\/]pages/,
   /[\\\/](strip-ansi|ansi-regex)[\\\/]/,
   /[\\\/]node_modules[\\\/]ol/]
```

Comment: Still not there. Seems something specific about next.js's webpack config. CRA's config has more things working out of the box...